# Customize html input range (bar slider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, range

I have the desire to customize an

```
<input type="range"...> </input>
```

I am using angular with angular material.
I need to have an area in the middle that is green, and two areas with the minimums and maximums that are red. The middle area size is defined by two values that I have.

Do you know a way to do this?
I don't want to use a D3 as that seems very complicated for such a small task.

Comment: Maybe you could start from this example of multi-range slider http://codepen.io/anandthakker/pen/marlo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not looking for a multi-range slider though. I would need  only one slider moving into one bar that has 3 areas of color.